# Is the sample mean complete sufficient for the Expectation when $X \sim F$ where $F$ is some symmetric distribution?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2... X_n$ be iid $\sim F$ where $F$ is any symmetric continuous distribution and let $\mid E(X)\mid<\infty$.

Is $\bar{x}$ complete sufficient for $E(x)=\int{xf(x)dx}$?

Assume that all parameters of $F$ except $E(x)=\mu$ are known and that the support of $X$ does not depend on $\mu$

Comment: I only ever see sufficiency defined for parameters that fully characterise the distribution. Here E(x) does not characterise F, and one could see the shape of F as another "parameter"; certainly it is additional information required to characterise F. In such a situation I only see joint sufficient statistics defined, for all characterising parameters together. I haven't come across a definition of sufficiency that covers one parameter only, if that parameter doesn't characterise the distribution. No such definition may exist, in which case the concept of sufficiency doesn't apply.

Comment: I made some changes. Suppose E(x) fully characterizes the distribution (it can have other parameters but all of these are assumed known). Also, let the support of $X$ not depend on $\mu$ to remove uniform

Comment: @jbowman: Do you mean Uniform(0,a) or something? Uniform(0,1) is a single distribution and doesn't have a free parameter.

Comment: @Lewian - oh, right, of course.  Thanks!

Comment: @Marj: Chances are one can still construct a counterexample based on the uniform. Take a mixture of 0.9*Uniform(0,2a)+0.1*something else symmetric about a with support on the full real line. Still the mean doesn't hold all information for estimating a.

Comment: @Lewian Thank you for the input. Yes, I see that such an example is possible. I guess what I'm basically interested in is how far I can stretch this generalization. For example, I know it's true for X is normal with known $\sigma$. I'd like to know for what else can I generalize this on

Comment: I guess that you'll have a hard time finding examples that work outside exponential families. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I suspect your question might be more usefully formulated as "Are there any continuous symmetric distributions with finite mean for which the sample mean is *not* a sufficient statistic?"

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Laplace distribution with known scale.  It is symmetric, continuous, and has support equal to the real line.  The unknown location parameter $\mu$ is equal to the expected value.  Yet the sample mean is not the sufficient statistic for $\mu$; the sufficient statistic in this case is the entire sample.

Comment: Although I believe that you are right, it may be helpful to show that the mean is not sufficient. (I'm too lazy trying it... just saying... ;-)

Comment: @Lewian - me too, that's why I didn't.  Oh well, with a little prodding from you, maybe I'll get it done ;-)